# Someone continuously up votes my questions and answers, putting my account in risk of suspension

Tags: support, voting, upvotes

I am not sure how to correctly describe this situation, but it is really weird and I am very nervous / scared right now.

Yesterday at about the same time, some one serially voted up my 4 top questions and 4 top answers, giving me 60+ reputation. But knowing stack Overflow rules, I know this will be corrected.

This morning, 45 out of 100 reputation is reversed. But, someone (I doubt to be the same person) serially upvoted me again! This time, he voted up my latest 10 answers, giving me 100+ reputation.

Normally I would be really happy if I gained reputation from my contributions, but such behaviour looks really programmatic, and **I think it is deliberately destructive to my account (as it might put my account at risk of being suspended?)**

Do not ask me whether this is from a sock puppet account. No, I only have one account and moderators are welcomed to verify that. It is just that I am really really afraid of my account being suspended, because of this. Can Stack Overflow investigate into this case?

Comment: _"as it might put my account at risk of being suspended?"_ As long there isn't an evidence for a voting fraud from a sock-puppet account of yours, I doubt so.

Comment: Key takeaways:  you're likely not going to get into trouble and the moderators will become aware of the situation should it begin to make a lot more noise than it is now.

Comment: Relax. You didn't do anything wrong, so you don't need to worry.

Comment: You don't have to worry too much about things you aren't directly involved in.There are processes in place on SO to ensure that people don't get reputation that they don't deserve. :) and  moderators are very careful when it comes to suspensions and deletions.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi This is one of those problems like your boss won't quit promoting you, teachers won't quit giving you straight A's, or clients won't quit overpaying you. I wish I had your problem!

Comment: @maroun-maroun However, it seems this user is suspended by now.

Comment: @jaySf It was due to a different reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I think it deliberately destructive to my account (as it might put my
>   account at risk of being suspended?).

Unless you are at the same physical location or have demonstrative ties to the person who does this, that is false. Just being the "victim" of serial upvoting is not grounds for a suspension. The person who did it might get into trouble if they keep doing it, but you won't.

It's of course a little disappointing to always have rep reversed, but if the guy keeps doing it the moderators will deal with him.

**tl;dr:** Unless its you who is doing this via sockpuppet, you have nothing to worry about.